# Ignore UI elements when clicking to move

Tags: unity

I have a click to move character that uses a Nav Mesh Agent and I want to ignore clicks that are made on UI elements. For example, I don't want clicking around in my inventory to move my player to the target under the inventory. The relevant part of the move script is very simple.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !playerHealth.isDead)
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        navMeshAgent.destination = hit.point;
    }
}
```

I would think that this is a common question raised among beginner developers or that it would be covered in beginner courses, but I can't seem to find the info I'm looking for when Googling around, so I'll ask it here.

So how do I get my Nav Mesh Agent to ignore clicks made on a particular UI element? How about ignoring clicks made to any and all UI elements? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) to avoid clicking UI elements.

Comment: Thanks, I added a LayerMask and deselected UI. Are there further steps? It's still not behaving correctly.

Comment: The Layer field of the Canvas in the inspector is set to UI as well, but my character still moves when I click on UI stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things

Change to this:

- `if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())`

and

- Make sure your graphics have the option Raycast target set to true.